# Verify the limit for this expression?

Tags: real-analysis

I need to verify the following limit. Let $z \, \epsilon\, [0,\,\infty)$ be a random variable with continuous probability density function  $g(z)$. For a constant $k >0$, define $F:\,(0,\infty)\rightarrow \, \mathcal{R}$ as,

\begin{align*} F(x) = \int^{\infty}_{0} \min\bigg\lbrace \frac{k}{x},\, z\bigg\rbrace g(z) dz\end{align*}

Verify that,
\begin{align*} \lim_{x\, \rightarrow\, 0} F(x) = E[z] \quad (*)\end{align*}

I'm using the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition. Clearly, $F(x) \, \epsilon\, (0, \,E[z])$. Suppose $(*)$ is true. Fix $\epsilon >0$. We need to find a $\delta>0$ such that $ 0 < x < \delta$ implies $ | F(x) - E[z]| < \epsilon$. If $\epsilon \geq E[z]$, any $\delta >0$ suffices.

Suppose $\epsilon < E[z]$. $0 < x < \delta$ which implies $F(x) > F(\delta)$ since $F(x)$ is strictly decreasing in $x$. If we set $\delta$ such that $F(\delta) = E[z]-\epsilon$, the proof is done, as long as a solution exists.
Since $F(x)$ is strictly decreasing in $x,\, F^{-1}$ exists, and $E[z]-\epsilon$ is in the range of $F(\cdot)$. Together, this implies there exist $\delta >0$ such that $\delta = F^{-1}(E[z]-\epsilon)$.

Can you verify if the proof is correct?